# How to draw a linear gradient along an arc in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create a colour selector tool, similar to a colour wheel but in the shape of a horse shoe.

I need to draw a linear gradient which follows an arc. Like this

[image]

The problem is

a) how to make a gradient follow the curve, instead of just going in one direction, and

b) how to fill the stroke of the arc and not the area enclosed by the arc

I've managed this on Android but have so far failed to get it working in iOS, so any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u find the solution of it.

Comment: Not exactly no. In the end we divided the Arc into smaller arcs with their own gradients and drew them separately.That way you don't really notice that the gradients don't actually follow the arc.